# Is the convex conjugate of the sum of infinity norm and Euclidean norm strictly convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is the following function
$$f(x)=\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n} \Big\{ x^\top y - \|y\|_\infty - \|y\|_2^2\Big\}$$
strictly convex?

Comment: Are you aware that $f(x) = \infty$ is possible?

Comment: @PaulFrost Thx. I edited the problem a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the function as $f(x) = (g+h)^*(y)$ with $g(y)=||y||_\infty$ and $h(y)=y^Ty$. This allows us to derive the following equivalence:
$$f(x) = (g+h)^*(y)=\inf_z \{ g^*(z)+h^*(y-z) \} = \inf_z \left\{ \frac{1}{4}z^Tz : ||y-z||_1\leq 1\right\}.$$
The function value is $0$ around $y=0$ (as long as $||y||_1 \leq 1$).

Comment: He seems to be asking about strict convexity.

Comment: @MichaelGrant You seem to be right! I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! My apologies. I forgot the square term in the expression. See the update.

Comment: @O.Richard updated.

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. Is it zero norm or 1-norm?

Comment: @O.Richard it is supposed to be the dual norm, so 1-norm, thanks.